# Resize UIImageView according to image size?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In IB we can use `command =` to resize the `UIImageView` to the original size of image.
I need to do it programmatically.I used `contentMode` but it resize image itself to match `UIImageView` size set in IB.
**Edit:**  I've tried

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ScanToVerifyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            STOScanToVerifyCell * verifyCell = (STOScanToVerifyCell *)cell;
            [verifyCell.scanStatusImage setHidden:NO];
            [verifyCell.scanStatusImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"point.png"]];
            [verifyCell.scanStatusImage sizeToFit];
```

But it is not working.What i'm doing wring?

Comment: Call sizeToFit on the image view.

Comment: I'v edited my question please have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
verifyCell.scanStatusImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

verifyCell.scanStatusImage .clipsToBounds = YES;

[verifyCell.scanStatusImage sizeToFit];
```

Hope This Helps You......!

Comment: Miner change to your code 'verifyCell.scanStatusImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;' instead of 'verifyCell.scanStatusImage = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;'

Answer (score 2):

it would be something like this: get image size by:

```
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
CGSize imgSize = img.size;
```

calculate scale ratio on width

```
float ratio=yourImageView.frame.size.width/imgSize.width;
```

check scaled height

```
float scaledHeight=imgSize.height*ratio;
if(scaledHeight < yourImageView.frame.size.height)
{
   //update height of your imageView frame with scaledHeight
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SizeToFit method will do the job.

Comment: Don't do it on the 'cellForRow' method. Do it on the layoutSubviews of the cell class.
I guess the autoresizing/auto layout mechanic change the size of the cell in every layout.